# How to find the area of the following triangle

Tags: geometry

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Let ABC be an isosceles triangle having two equal sides of length $20$ cm. and the angle between the 
>   two equal sides is $45^{\circ}$. Then I have to find the area of $\triangle ABC$ . But I can not use any trigonometric formulae using $\sin$, $\cos$ etc. It is a ninth grade problem .

Can someone please help? Thanks in advance for your time.

ADDENDUM : Though my problem has been solved , but I have got a similar problem which is identical with the one posted above apart from the fact that the angle between the two equal sides( each of length $20$ cm.) is given by $30^{\circ}$. In that case how can I solve the problem ?

Comment: Did you try finding the height using pythagorean theorem in $45-45-90$ triangle formed when you drop a perpendicular to one of the congruent sides ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I accomplished this problem...

Suppose we have $\triangle ABC$. I've drawn the triangle such that $A$ is on the right, $C$ is at the top, and $B$ is on the left. $AC = 20$ cm and $AB = 20$ cm. Drop a straight line down from $C$ to $AB$. Call the point where they meet $D$. We know that $AC = 20$ cm and that $A = 45^\circ$.

We know that $\triangle ADC$ is a $45^\circ-45^\circ-90^\circ$ triangle. The hypotenuse $AC = 20$ cm. Thus, $AD = DC = \frac{20}{\sqrt2}$ cm. Area of a triangle is $A_\triangle = \frac12bh$, where we now know $DC = h$. So the area of $\triangle ABC$ is 
$A_{\triangle ABC} = \frac{1}{2}(20)\left(\frac{20}{\sqrt2}\right)$cm$^2 = 100\sqrt2$ cm$^2$.

Comment: Read this again if you haven't already. I've fixed all the unit errors and typos (I hope!)

Comment: what exactly was the point in circumventing using the area formula on the triangle to begin with, since we knew the equal sides were perpendicular?

Comment: Yeah, I could've done it better. But hey, as long as it works! Edited to reflect that change.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. got it..Crystal work..

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If the angle between the equal sides of length $l$ is $\pi/4$ than the height with respect one of this sides is $l \sin (\pi/4)$.

If you can not use $\sin$, note that the height with respect to one side is the side of the square that has $l$ as diagonal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can not use $\sin$ related theorem.

Comment: I've added an other hint to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What happens if you reflect the triangle along the hypotenuse?

Comment: wow..got your point..Then it becomes rhombus...I think i can take it forword..

Comment: but specifically which type of rhombus? What will the two 45 degrees will add to give?

Comment: I do not get it...It will give me rhombus with two opposite angles of $45 ^{\circ}$ each and other two opposite angles of  $135 ^{\circ}$ each.

Comment: I still could not finish it . We can find the area 
of rhombus in 2 ways and from that we get the relation
 $20 h=\frac12 ab$, where $h$ is the height of the rhombus 
and $a,b$ are the lengths of diagonals.. Now, I am stuck.

Comment: Remembering the formula for the area of a triangle is $A=\frac{bh}{2}$, forgetting about the rhombus altogether, what is the base length, and what is the height length? Hint: in the triangle, these two are perpedicular (they meet at 90 degrees)